# Delphi program crashing in DevExpress initialisation

Tags: delphi, crash, initialization, devexpress

I am trying to revive an old Delphi app, written in Delphi 7, and using `DevExpress` components.

But it is crashing on start up in this function:

```
function TcxRegisteredClasses.GetIndexByClass(AClass: TClass): Integer;
begin
  Result := FItems.IndexOfObject(TObject(AClass));
end;
```

The `Self` is `nil`. It runs through sucessfully a number of times, then dies. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

TIA
Mark

Comment: Can you check the stack when your prog crashes? I just added a breakpoint in our app - most of the calls to `TcxRegisteredClasses.GetIndexByClass` get `FRegisteredEditProperties` as `Self` via a call to `GetRegisteredEditProperties`. Maybe you can set a data breakpoint on this variable to check where it gets changed.

Comment: I take it that you didn't see this crash "back then" when you first wrote the program? Did you update your DevEx version? Which version are you using?

Comment: Are you using run-time packages at all?

Comment: Andy: It is not using run-time packages.

Comment: Uli: I have only been told that it used to run. I've taken it over from another developer who took it over from someone else who is not interested :(

Comment: Uli: I have done some more research into the problem. The offending call comes from the initialization section of cxGridTableView. It has the line `cxGridRegisteredViews.Register(TcxGridTableView, 'Table');`. The variable `cxGridRegisteredViews` is initialized in the initialization of unit cxGridCustomView. Of course cxGridTableView includes cxGridCustomView in its uses clause, so this seems to be a bug in the compiler not sorting out the order to call the initialization sections.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints on that and the `cxGridRegisteredViews := TcxGridRegisteredViews.Create` line check that?

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint on that line. It gets called if I have done a Build All and then f9 to run. But if I have not done a Build All, it doesn't get run. That doesn't seem to make any sense. Any ideas?